# In Scala, how do I access a case class's private constructor from its companion object

Tags: scala, constructor, private-methods, companion-object

I have the following code defined (in Scala IDE/Scala Worksheet with Scala 2.10):

```
object WorkSheet1 {
  object A {
    def apply(s: String, huh: Boolean = false): A = A(s)
  }
  case class A (s: String)
  //case class A private (s: String)
  val a = A("Oh, Hai")
}
```

And I successfully receive the following output:

> a  : public_domain.WorkSheet1.A = A(Oh, Hai)

However, when I comment out the existing `case class A (s: String)` and uncomment out the other one (containing "**private**"), I receive the following compiler error: "constructor A in class A cannot be accessed in object WorkSheet1".

It was my understanding that a companion object had access to all of it's companion class's private parts. Heh. Uh...seriously, though. What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it private for anybody but As

```
object WorkSheet1 {
  object A {
    def apply(s: String, huh: Boolean = false): A = A(s)
  }
  case class A private[A](s: String)
  val a = A("Oh, Hai", false)
}
```

I added false to solve ambiguity between object apply and case class constructor which is publicly visible.

Comment: Thank you. It does appear that adding "[A]" resolved the compiler error. However, why is the compiler complaining of an ambiguity without the adding of the "false" when the val a only has access to object A.apply (and shouldn't see or be impacted by the case class constructor)?

Comment: You could use [`DummyImplicit`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$$DummyImplicit) instead of your dummy Boolean value.

Comment: Or change `A(s)` to `new A(s)` to be explicit about wanting to call the constructor and not the `apply`